# To look if the date is within 7 days in Django

Tags: django, django-views

```
class Order(models.Model):
     date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

I have date_ordered field inside order model. And now i want to check if the date_ordered and today's date is within 7 days or not inside views.py .

For today's date i have used :   current_day = datetime.datetime.now()  ( if i need to use another, please suggest)

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


current_date = date.today()
future_date = current_date + timedelta(days=7)

orders = Order.objects.filter(
    date_ordered__range=(current_date, future_date),
)
```

**Warning**: Filtering a DateTimeField with dates won’t include items on the last day, because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given date”.

Comment: Hey man , I bumped into some problem .
I have this in views.py 
`orders_completed = Order.objects.filter(customer=customer, complete=True)
orders= []
 for i in orders_completed :
     ordered_date = i.date_ordered
      valid_date = ordered_date + timedelta(days=2)
        if Order.objects.filter(id=i.id , date_ordered__range=(ordered_date ,valid_date) ):
            orders.append(i)`

 and an order was placed in september 18 , but today is 25th sep
and my order is still displaying in frontend.
Can you please help me in this

Comment: Please ask it in another question. @ManasManSingh

Comment: i have written another question below , can you please look

Comment: Hey , can you please answer this , i have asked another question for this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336951/using-range-in-datetime-in-django